# Why I need to rebuild the xamarin android solution always when debugging

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net, rebuild

I have to rebuild the xamarin android solution every time after doing changes. I am using SQLite-net as database and Database calls are not working properly if I build and run. It takes about 6-10 minutes to rebuild the solution. So rebuilding solutions takes too much time. I have attached Options --> Project & Solutions --> Build & run settings here. Any help ?

[image: build&run setting in vs 2017]